# Python Nested Loops And Else Clause in List Comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have two lists:

```
lst = ['Go','Go','Go','Go','Dont Go!','Go','Go','Go','Dont Go!','Go'] 
tls = ['G', 'Go', 'Go1', 'Go2', 'Go3']
```

I need to check for each element in tls if it exists in lst then to output that element, otherwise to output NaN.

I need output to be list like:

```
['Go', 'Go', 'Go', 'Go', nan, 'Go', 'Go', 'Go', nan, 'Go']
```

I managed to achieve this by using nested for loops:

```
ml = []
for t in tls:
    for l in lst:
        if t in lst:
            if t !=l:
                ml.append(np.nan)
            else:
                ml.append(t)
        else:
            pass
```

Is it possible to add else clause in this list comprehension in order to achieve the same result?

```
[t for t in tls for l in lst if t ==l]
```

The output for this list comprehension:

```
['Go', 'Go', 'Go', 'Go', 'Go', 'Go', 'Go', 'Go']
```

Expected output:

```
['Go', 'Go', 'Go', 'Go', nan, 'Go', 'Go', 'Go', nan, 'Go']
```

Thank You.

Comment: Note, it's a relatively minor optimisation but since you're repeatedly looking up values in `tls` it is more efficient to make it a set: `tls = {'G', 'Go', 'Go1', 'Go2', 'Go3'}`

Comment: Your nested loop code is doing a lot of unnecessary stuff. You only need the top level `for` loop, and the `if t in lst` test (and an `else` block` for it). All the rest is cruft. You can turn that explicit loop and `if`/`else` into a list comprehension, but since you have an `else` term you'll need to use the `x if condition else y` conditional expression, rather than adding an `if condition` clause at the end of the comprehension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you could do so using a list comprehension. For a better performance you could take a set of `tls` reducing in this way the complexity of checking for membership to `O(1)`:

```
lst = ['Go','Go','Go','Go','Dont Go!','Go','Go','Go','Dont Go!','Go'] 
tls = set(['G', 'Go', 'Go1', 'Go2', 'Go3'])

[i if i in tls else float('nan') for i in lst]
#['Go', 'Go', 'Go', 'Go', nan, 'Go', 'Go', 'Go', nan, 'Go']
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to check for each element in `lst` whether that element matches with any element in the list `tls`. Then try this :

```
[t if t in tls else np.nan for t in lst]
```

**Output** :

```
['Go', 'Go', 'Go', 'Go', nan, 'Go', 'Go', 'Go', nan, 'Go']
```

Answer (score 0):

Python [`math`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#module-math) module also introduce [`math.nan`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.nan) from [Python 3.5](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350/).

> A floating-point “not a number” (NaN) value. Equivalent to the output of float('nan').

Try this,

```py
>>> from math import nan
>>> 
>>> lst = ['Go','Go','Go','Go','Dont Go!','Go','Go','Go','Dont Go!','Go']
>>> tls = ['G', 'Go', 'Go1', 'Go2', 'Go3']
>>> [i if i in tls else nan for i in lst]
['Go', 'Go', 'Go', 'Go', nan, 'Go', 'Go', 'Go', nan, 'Go']
```